# AngularJS : How to filter one object attribute with passed argument

Tags: angularjs

I have meet a problem, I try to filter the query result, I want to filter the item.type.  The filter value is bounded on the input field.
I try the following code, but it doesn't work. How can I make it correct? Thanks.

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">
Current filter: {{query}}
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter : {type : 'query'}">
<td>{{item.type}}</td>
<td>{{item.host}}</td>

 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `filter`

```
$scope.filterByType = function(item) {
    return item.type == "query";
}
```

And the use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter : filterByType">
```

Comment: I tried, but it not work. I put the code in the controller:function ShoppingController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/shop.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
        $scope.filterByType = function(item) {
            return item.type == $scope.query;
        };
    }

Comment: I update the code: $scope.filterByType = function(item) {
            if ($scope.query == '') {
                return item;
            }
            return item.type == $scope.query;
        }; but the problem is when page initialize there is no value, input any charactars and then delete them to blank input, the items show. How to resovle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes:

```
filter : {type : query}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vTcCK/)

Answer (score 0):

I try the following code, it will return all when no input in the query filter.

```
    $scope.filterByType = function(item) {
        if ($scope.query == undefined || $scope.query.length == 0) {
            return item;
        }
        return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query.toString().toLowerCase()) >=0 ;

    };
```